# FCM notification is not occurring in Android 10 mobiles while the app is in background or closed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM notification is not occurring in Android 10 mobiles while the app is in background or closed.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            Log.e("FCM", "onMessageReceived");
    
            if (new Helper(this).isLoggedIn()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirebaseChatService.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 99, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, pendingIntent);
                Log.e("FCM", "scheduled");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please restructure your code with Stack Overflow's code formatting feature.

Comment: @CHiLLar, in your log cat are you able to observe : "onMessageReceived". If no then check if you have initiated FCM. To trigger notification you need to have device token and then from Firebase console you may trigger it.

Comment: In all mobiles having versions 9.0 or low, my app is having FCM but in Android 10.0 version mobiles FCM are not coming while app is in background or closed